# Looking for best guidance to migrate legacy web service (ASMX) to WCF

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, service, asmx

Our company has many legacy web service (ASMX) and if want to manually convert those legacy web service (ASMX) to WCF then it may take good time. so I am looking for best guidance to migrate or convert legacy web service (ASMX) to WCF very quickly. so discuss all the possible ways in detail.

is there any tool exist which can seamlessly convert legacy web service (ASMX) to WCFvery quickly.

is there any option to avoid interface in WCFwhen we convert legacy web service (ASMX) to WCFvery quickly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the topic of converting ASMX web service to WCF is already well covered on the internet: (e.g.)

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738697(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/312490/Migrating-ASMX-Services-To-WCF-services
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2006/10/05/phased-migration-from-asmx-to-wcf.aspx

I suspect that you are looking for a way to “shortcut” the process.  To that end, I think the implementation of WCF Web Services is sufficiently straightforward that any workaround compromises will not be worthwhile. Therefore, my advice is to prioritize your web services and start converting.

Good luck.